# Tool for Generating database schema diagram from MySQL query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, database-schema

May I know is there any tool for generating database schema diagram from MySQL query dump from phpmyadmin? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"From MySQL query" is vague - do you mean from a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` query?

Regardless, with the right access, [MySQL Workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-reverse-engineering.html) will reverse engineer the schema and create a diagram for you.

Answer (score 0):

try MySQL Workbench, follow below link
http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Answer (score 0):

Try the MySQL workbench. It is buggy at times but will do the job. It is a official oracle product as well.